# How to integrate ASIHTTPRequest in ARC

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, asihttprequest

There are many errors when integrating ASIHTTPRequest library in arc mode. Is there a proper way to integrate non arc library.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if your project's using ARC, click project name -> select target -> build phase -> compiler sources.

Set compiler flag `-fno-objc-arc` for all ASIHTTPRequest source files.

Answer (score 7):

ASIHTTPRequest hasn't been supported for a couple of years now. As such, it is very outdated and does not support ARC.

A newer library, called AFNetworking, can be found on Github [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), and fully supports ARC, so you might want to think about using it instead.

Comment: +1 It also supports blocks, which ASI does not (making it cleaner to use)

Answer (score 4):

I find a ASIHTTPRequest With ARC and working complete you can download

from here [ASIHTTPRequest-With-ARC](https://github.com/jayeshkavathiya/ASIHTTPRequest-With-ARC)
enjoy.......

you can also find json with ARC at here

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Better to add Reachbility.h with ARC

Comment: What is the license for the code? Can I assume that it is this one? https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/blob/master/LICENSE